# Add degree symbol to label

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to add degree symbol to this label in xaml.Please tell me how to do it?

```
<Label Content="{Binding CelsiusTemperature}"  />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`ContentStringFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contentstringformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for `Label`:

> Gets or sets a composite string that specifies how to format the `Content` property if it is displayed as a string.

Example:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=CelsiusTemperature}" 
       ContentStringFormat="{}{0}°" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a `TextBlock` instead of a `Label` and set the [`StringFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx) property of the Binding:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding CelsiusTemperature, StringFormat={}{0}°}"/>
```

---

If for whatever reason you really need a Label, you may set its `ContentStringFormat` property instead of the Binding's `StringFormat`, or just use a TextBlock as the Label's `Content`:

```
<Label>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CelsiusTemperature, StringFormat={}{0}°}"/>
</Label>
```